# com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction > Android resource linking failed

Tags: flutter

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.example.awrim_tech:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
> error: resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents (aka com.example.awrim_tech:style/Theme.MaterialComponents) not found.
> error: failed linking references.
> giving these errror

**Here is the solution for these error go to app level build.gradle file
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' // Or the latest version
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' // Or the latest version
and go to android inside app inside src inside res inside values there is styles.xml file
see this is properly there or not
**
.

@drawable/launch_background
    
         `This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
</style>`

Answer (score 0):

**Add these dependencies in your app level build.gradle file**

**implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' // Or the latest version
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' // Or the latest version**